# Featured Questions should display the higher bounties first

Tags: feature-request, bounty

I think that it is more motivating for somebody to give a higher bounty, knowing that it will be closer to the top on the featured questions section.

Then, questions with the same bounties should be listed in chronological order.

Answer (score 3):

I guess I'll shed some light on what currently happens. The featured questions are sorted by the time remaining in ascending order. So the bounties that are ending the soonest show atop. The point of the featured list is to show questions that have bounties, or are "featured" and to get eyes on those questions. If a bounty for 500 points has 4 days left and one for 50 points has just a few hours, which is more important? In the eyes of the system the bounty that's been hanging around for the last 5 days with no one awarded is far more important than the one that is higher.

Those who wish to sniff out the higher bounties can do it easily enough by skimming the list since it rarely grows larger than one page.

Comment: I just believe that it is quite unfair to see a 500 bounty on the bottom of the list. It is 10 times greater than the 50 bounty which can be at the top of all. If a 50 bounty expires then the questioner should seriously consider adding a higher bounty. Now there is no real motivation, because you are not sure whether your question will be seen or not.

Comment: The 500 rep bounty will work it's way to the top just like the 50 rep bounty did.

Comment: Low rep user's can't offer 500 rep for bounty, ignoring them is not fair

Comment: I just think that it is more fair... A user that helps (and so they can offer 500 ref) should have more chances to be helped! And you're not actually ignoring the low rep users. A question in the featured questions section usually get the attention they need.

Comment: @hakermania by that logic what's the harm in having it this way?

Comment: Notice the word 'usually'. The topper the better